# Generate a secure double defined on range [0.0d - 1.0d] (both inclusive)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I need to know how to generate a secure double defined on range [0.0 - 1.0] both inclusive.
I generate two big `ulong` numbers with `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class, make sure that the second number is greater or equals to the first number and then divide the first number by the second number and cast result to `double`. Ideally, numbers **0.0d** and **1.0d** should be included in this range, but they're never included. It must be something with mantissa with `double` values. Do you know how to fix it?

Code I used:

```
public static class Randomizer
{
    private static readonly RandomNumberGenerator RngLow;
    private static readonly RandomNumberGenerator RngHigh;

    static Randomizer()
    {
        RngLow = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        RngHigh = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a next double value defined on range [0,0 - 1,0]
    /// </summary>
    public static double NextDouble()
    {
        ulong low = GetNextLow();
        ulong high = GetNextHigh(low);

        return ((double) low) / high;
    }

    private static ulong GetNextLow()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeof(ulong)];
        RngLow.GetBytes(bytes);
        ulong number = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);
        return number;
    }

    private static ulong GetNextHigh(ulong low)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeof(ulong)];

        while (true)
        {
            Array.Clear(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            RngHigh.GetBytes(bytes);
            ulong number = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);

            if (number < low)
            {
                continue;
            }

            return number;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show some code of your calculation. The way you describe it, I suppose you will get `0.0d` most of the time and `1.0d` in some rare occations. But never something in between ...

Comment: I added my code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

As Jeroen Mostert stated in the comments, this is not a *secure*  random number generator because some results are more probable than others. For instance `1` is about twice as probable as `.5` and four times as probable as `0.25`

---

That's a problem with the precision of `double`. Eventhough `double.MaxValue` is by order of magnitudes greater than `ulong.MaxValue` (about `1.8 x 10^308` vs `1.9 x 10^19`) it only has a precision of about 15-17 digits ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)). So when casting a very large ulong to double, you lose some of the ulongs digits. Might not be a problem for most of your results, but for the border cases 0.0d and 1.0d. I don't know, how many runs you took but:

- `0.0d` must occur if and only if `GetNextLow()` returns `0ul`. That's quite a rare situation for a 64bit random number generator. In any other case the result of the division must and will be different from `0.0d`.
- `1.0d` must occur if and only if `GetNextLow()` and `GetNextHigh()` return the same number. That's an even rarer situation for a 64bit random number generator. But even if `low == high`, because of the cast to double, you may lose precision, and the result of the division may differ from `1.0d` (depending on how the division is implemented)

So I'd suggest something like the following

```
public static double NextDouble()
{
  ulong low = GetNextLow();
  if (low == 0) return 0.0d;

  ulong high = GetNextHigh(low);
  if (low == high) return 1.0d;

  return ((double) low) / high;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Yet another problem with your code is, that getting the `high` number may take quite long. Imagine `low` got the random value `ulong.MaxValue - 1`. Thus there are only two possible values for `high` anymore: `ulong.MaxValue - 1` and `ulong.MaxValue`. But your random generator in `GetNextHigh()` is generating numbers over and over until it hits one of these two allowed results. So you should also get rid of the `GetNextHigh()` function, and just call `GetNextLow()` twice and swap divisor and dividend if necessary.

```
public static double NextDouble()
{
  ulong low = GetNextLow();
  if (low == 0) return 0.0d;

  ulong high = GetNextLow();
  if (low == high) return 1.0d;

  return low < high
    ? ((double) low) / high
    : ((double) high) / low;
}
```

Comment: You won't get an exception for `double` division, even with `checked`; `0.0d / 0.0d` is just a NaN. Even with these changes the distribution is obviously not uniform, since then the cases `0` and `1` would be equally probable. (Fixing that in a way that doesn't tank performance is not trivial, though.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes you are right with the exception, I was thinking about integer division. And of course you are also right with the argument of uniformity. But with an algorithm like the above, this can never be achieved because there are `ulong.MaxValues - 1 ` combinations to get `1`, but less than `ulong.MaxValues / 2` combinations to get `0.5` and less than `ulong.MaxValues/4` combinations to get `0.25` and so on and so forth

Comment: Then how do I get a truly secure generator, except simple Random class? But even with Random 1.0d is not included. How do math guys deal with case when they calculate probability in statistics and the result comes as P = 1.0? Do they use some libraries for that??

Comment: Oh, I see now. I can generate only a single ULONG value and divide it by ULONG.MAX

Comment: @NickReshetinsky Yes, that would be a possiblity. If the ULONG generator is uniformly distributed, also the division result will be -- at least theoretically. There are of course still the mentioned technical limits with the double precision.